# JQuery Post Array to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I know there are many questions about this, but none of which seem to allow me to understand.  I have the following JS code:

```
function ClickToSave() {
var data1 = CKEDITOR.instances.textToBeSaved1.getData();
var data2 = CKEDITOR.instances.textToBeSaved2.getData();
var data3 = CKEDITOR.instances.textToBeSaved3.getData();
var data4 = CKEDITOR.instances.textToBeSaved4.getData();
var data5 = CKEDITOR.instances.textToBeSaved5.getData();
$.post('/admin/post_handler.php', {
page_content_1 : data1,
page_content_2 : data2,
page_content_3 : data3,
page_content_4 : data4,
page_content_5 : data5
})}
```

I'm trying to post this from CKEditor for a PHP page to pickup and know which data goes where.  The JS is meant to save several inline DIV ID's simultaneously when the user clicks Save.  I had this code working great when only using one DIV ID, but multiple is proving to be more challenging.

I'm having a little trouble replying to people as this site makes posts a little odd.  The above code won't work.  The following code does work:

```
function ClickToSave() {
var data1 = CKEDITOR.instances.textToBeSaved1.getData();
$.post('/admin/post_handler.php', {
page_content_1 : data1
})}
```

The HTML/PHP is as follows:

```
<?php echo '<div id="textToBeSaved1" contenteditable="true">'.$contentHere.'</div><button onclick="ClickToSave()">Save</button>'; ?>
```

The post_handler.php file only has this for testing reasons:

```
<?php file_put_contents('post_errors.php', $_POST['page_content_1']); ?>
```

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: So what problem are you actually having?  What specific aspect is not working? From you question you have not provided enough information for us to know whether you may have a problem with `CKEDITOR`, with the actual jQuery POST, or with the PHP backend script.

Comment: The problem is this script is not sending anything to post_handler.php.  This is inline editing, no textareas are used, only a submit button.  CKEditor grabs the data by id, textToBeSaved1, 2, etc.  The submit button launches the JS code to post the data to post_handler.php.  I can only get this code to work if there's only one var and one page_content to pass to post_handler.php.

Comment: One need to learn how to get the data of all the Ckeditor instances at a time instead of specifying a specific ID like this

Comment: I think I might not be pulling the posted data correctly in the PHP file.  I'm saying file_put_contents('post_errors.php', $_POST['page_content_1']);

Answer (score 0):

On the receiver PHP side `$_POST['page_content_1']` will contain `data1` and so on.

Comment: I write the output of page_content_1 to a file so I can see if it works.  It only works when there's only page_content_1.  When I add 2 - 5 it does nothing, not even a file is written.

Comment: Please post the HTML code, that might help us figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Please include the HTML which **sends** the data.

Comment: User2270404, the HTML code is <button onclick="ClickToSave()">Save</button>.  That launches the JS which then the JS launches post_handler.php which writes the output to a file.

Comment: I've discovered that if not all textToBeSaved id's are populated the JS won't work.  Therefore the JS needs to check if the value is null before trying to assign it.  I know very little to no JS, and that is the entire issue here.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar, but I handled it with an array in HTML like

```
<textarea name="editor[]" class="" ></textarea>
<textarea name="editor[]" class="" ></textarea>
<textarea name="editor[]" class="" ></textarea>
<textarea name="editor[]" class="" ></textarea>
```

in PHP I got the values by using $x = $_REQUEST['editor'] and saved it with a

foreach ( $x as $var ) { do something }  or  $_REQUEST['editor'][0] is the first,  $_REQUEST['editor'][1] is the second editor values.